# Odoo 8 link 1 User to 1 Point of Sale

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale

I need to link 1 User to 1 POS (Point Of Sale) in Odoo v8.0.

That is, 1 user will be able to use only the assigned POS.

How can I do that? Is there any module which does this?

I searched here and in Odoo Help forum and even posted there, but i'm getting no answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create module and extend the User model. It is `res.users` odoo object.

Comment: I finally made that module from 0 without inheriting, just creating the needed fields and implementing its view.
Seems our inheritance was breaking somehow the res.partner.

Comment: `res.partner` it is just contact. users use `res.users` object. Each `res.users` related with contact. As I understood, you added new fields to original model from odoo repository?